# How to style a link that contains an svg and get rid of the extra 4px?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'd like to add a `box-shadow` focus style to an `<a>` that wraps an `<svg>`:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
  <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
    <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
    </path>
  </svg>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.focus { /* not using :focus for demo purposes */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 4px #f14848;
}
svg {
  display: block; /* this is to get rid of the extra 4px at the bottom */
}
```

However, with this setup, the `box-shadow` doesn't look right:

[image]

Adding `display: inline-block` to `<a>`, causes the `box-shadow` to look right. But, then the unwanted 4px appears:

[image]

Looks like having `display: table` on the `<a>` instead solves the issue:

[image]

But, is this the most idiomatic way to solve this?

---

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

a.focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 4px #f14848;
}

a.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

a.table {
  display: table;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>No focus</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="focus">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>No focus (inline-block)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="inline-block">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus (inline-block)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="inline-block focus">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>No focus (table)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="table">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus (table)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="table focus">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the box-shadow to be inset? Or is the aim to get it looking like the result from display table without actually using display table?

Comment: @ksav Nope. I'd like to use the `box-shadow` style as described in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to `a`. Since in `inline-block`, elements sits on `baseline`, that 4px is actually the reserved space for character descenders.

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  /* add this */
  vertical-align: top;
}

a.focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 4px #f14848;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>No focus</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="focus">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align: middle;` should get the inline-block example looking like the table example.

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

a.focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 4px #f14848;
}

a.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a.table {
  display: table;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>No focus</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="focus">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>No focus (inline-block)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="inline-block">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus (inline-block)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="inline-block focus">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>No focus (table)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="table">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus (table)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="table focus">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you may have misread the question

Comment: Haha that is highly likely

Answer (score 0):

apply the box shadow to a.focus svg  which I believe will also be the most efficient way to achieve your result.

```css
body {
  margin: 100px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}



a.focus {
display:flex;
align-items:center;
width:25%;
box-shadow: 0 0 0px 4px #f14848;
}

a.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

a.table {
  display: table;
}

svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>No focus</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" >
    
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
        
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="focus" id='aflex'>
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
          <p>some text</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>No focus (inline-block)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="inline-block">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus (inline-block)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="inline-block focus">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div>No focus (table)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="table">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
          <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
          </path>
        </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>With focus (table)</div>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="table focus">
      <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="GitHub">
            <path d="M15.846 4C9.304 4 4 9.148 4 15.5c0 5.08 3.394 9.388 8.102 10.91.593.105.809-.25.809-.555 0-.273-.01-.996-.016-1.955-3.295.694-3.99-1.542-3.99-1.542-.54-1.329-1.316-1.682-1.316-1.682-1.076-.713.081-.7.081-.7 1.19.083 1.815 1.186 1.815 1.186 1.057 1.757 2.772 1.25 3.448.956.107-.743.413-1.25.752-1.538-2.63-.29-5.397-1.276-5.397-5.683 0-1.255.462-2.281 1.22-3.085-.122-.29-.529-1.46.116-3.043 0 0 .995-.31 3.258 1.179a11.67 11.67 0 012.966-.388c1.006.005 2.02.132 2.966.388 2.261-1.488 3.254-1.18 3.254-1.18.647 1.584.24 2.753.118 3.044.76.804 1.218 1.83 1.218 3.085 0 4.418-2.77 5.39-5.41 5.674.426.355.805 1.057.805 2.13 0 1.537-.015 2.777-.015 3.154 0 .308.214.665.815.553 4.703-1.524 8.095-5.83 8.095-10.908C27.694 9.148 22.39 4 15.846 4" fill-rule="evenodd">
            </path>
          </svg>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach unfortunately limits the possibility of adding link text next to the icon.

Comment: modified to accommodate link text next to icon